# Unable to Read VSAN Datstore Items using powercli, it is returning UUIDs instead of Name

Tags: windows, powershell, datastore, powercli, vsan

I'm trying to upload an ISO to VSAN datastore using `Powercli`. I want to check if there is a folder named `ISO`, if not, create and upload to that folder.

For other DS Types (`VMFS`), I have not faced any issue. I was mounting the DS on a PSDrive using the `PSProvider` as `VIMDatastore`. I was able to do the same for VSAN, but in the `Name` and `PSChildName` property, I'm getting `UUIDs`, hence unable to read the contents of the DS.

Any other way I can read the contents, Create a Folder and Copy the ISO?